# Ext is not defined error

Tags: android, cordova, sencha-touch, extjs, sencha-touch-2

I'm creating a Android app with Eclipse, PhoneGap and using Sencha Touch for the `assets\www` files

However when I try to run the application I get this error from logcat:

```
09-11 14:11:01.019: E/Web Console(4700): Uncaught ReferenceError: Ext is not defined at file:///android_asset/www/app.js:16
```

Although I have placed:

- assets\www\sencha-touch.js
- assets\www\sencha-touch.css

I copied from my *sencha-touch-2.0.1.1* folder

What other things I need to place in the `assets\www` folder?

It's really weird because when I run the Sencha Touch app from within my desktop the mobile apps works fine with Google Chrome and Firefox, so I am not really sure what's happening.

Comment: I have resolved the "Ext is not defined error" but when the application runs I get a blank white screen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the default folder the SDK expects to contain the complete set of JS, CSS, and HTML files.

You need to also keep phonegap.js in www folder
Also try copying resources form Sencha-touch-2.0.1.1 folder and also sencha-touch-debug.js(not necesary).

Comment: I need to put the phonegap.js even if my Sencha touch app is not yet using any PhoneGap functions? I tried another Sencha touch app and it works properly, it seems that the problem is with my Touch app, I still need to verify though.\

Answer (score 0):

did u add the filepath of senchatouch.js and senchatouch.css inside index.html file.If didn't add the below lines in index.html
1."<"link rel="stylesheet" href="sencha-touch.css" type="text/css"">"
2."<"link rel="stylesheet" href="sencha-touch.css" type="text/css"">"